# How to use rollup function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rollup

I am trying to use a group by rollup oracle function, but not getting it right.

Here is my data format (`L1_Proj_ID` is Level 1 Project ID etc.....)

```
Proj_ID  Hours_Charged L1_Proj_ID  L2_Proj_ID L3_Proj_ID     L4_Proj_ID  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------  
1100.10         20       1100        1100.10    Null           Null  
1100.11.01      30       1100        1100.11    1100.11.01     Null  
1100.11.02      40       1100        1100.11    1100.11.02     Null  
1100.12.01.01   50       1100        1100.12    1100.12.01     1100.12.01.01
```

I need to get the roll up totals and my output should be

```
Proj_Level  Hours_Charged  
--------------------------  
1100            140  
1100.10          20  
1100.11          70  
1100.11.01       30  
1100.11.02       40   
1100.12          50   
1100.12.01       50  
1100.12.01.01    50
```

Please, Let me know if there any other easy way to do.

As of now i can get this data like...

```
select 
  L1_proj_id, 
  sum(hours_charged) as hours_charged 
from table  
group by 
  l1_proj_id 
union all   
select 
  L2_proj_id, 
  sum(hours_charged) as hours_charged 
from table 
group by 
  21_proj_id  
union all  
select 
  L3_proj_id, 
  sum(hours_charged) as hours_charged 
from table 
group by 
  l3_proj_id  
union all  
select 
  L4_proj_id, 
  sum(hours_charged) as hours_charged 
from table 
group by 
  l4_proj_id
```

Comment: Your data structure is odd. ROLLUP(col1, col2) gives you the aggregate results for: GROUP BY col1, col2; GROUP BY col1; Without GROUP BY. But, you have your id's in 5 different columns.

Comment: @NeriaNachum As of now i can get this data select L1_Proj_ID, sum (hours_charged) Hours_charges from table group by l1_proj_id union all select L2_Proj_ID, sum (hours_charged) Hours_charges from table group by l2_proj_id union all select L3_Proj_ID, sum (hours_charged) Hours_charges from table group by l3_proj_id union all select L4_Proj_ID, sum (hours_charged) Hours_charges from table group by l4_proj_id

Comment: That's the way I thought about. It's not pretty but I don't exactly understand why you have 5 id's columns that represent the same id(?).
For example, instead of having one row like this: 1100.10         20       1100        1100.10, it will be much more flexible to have three columns like this: 1100.10         20;       1100        20;        1100.10         20;

Answer (score 1):

This does not use `rollup`, but I think it might deliver your results.  In essence, I unnest your columns into rows.  It should also be *relatively* easy to scale if your content changes.

```
with levels as (
  select level id
  from dual
  connect by level <= 4
),
all_data as (
  select
    case l.id
      when 1 then l1_proj_id
      when 2 then l2_proj_id
      when 3 then l3_proj_id
      when 4 then l4_proj_id
    end as project_id,
    t.hours_charged
  from
    table t,
    levels l
)
select
  project_id, sum (hours_charged) as hours_charged
from all_data
where project_id is not null
group by project_id
```